# How do I save selected value dropdown in .Net Core MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

How I save the Guid PK to the database?

Model Medicine:

```
public class Medicine
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MedicineType MedicineTypes { get; set; } 
    public Guid MedicineTypeId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<SelectListItem> SelectMedicineTypes{ get; set; }
}
```

Model MedicineType:

```
 public class MedicineType
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller:

```
EFDataContext db = new EFDataContext();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create(Medicine medicine)
        {
            MedicineType x = new MedicineType();
            if (x.Id == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Select Medicine Types");
            }
            Guid SelectedValue = x.Id;
            List<MedicineType> type = new List<MedicineType>();
            type = (from MedicineType in db.MedicineType
                    select MedicineType).ToList();
            type.Insert(0, new MedicineType { Id = Guid.Empty, Name = "Select Medicine Type" });
            ViewBag.type = type;
            return View();
        }
```

and I'm calling `SelectList` from my controller to my view:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("MedicineTypeId", new SelectList(ViewBag.type, "Id", "Name"), new {
 @class = "form-control" })
                    @if (ViewBag.type != null)
                    {
                        @ViewBag.SelectedValue
                    }
```

How do I save the dropdown selected value to the database?

this my post controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateMedicine(Medicine medicine)
    {

        ModelState.Remove("Id");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            medicine.Created = DateTime.Now;
            db.Medicine.Add(medicine);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
            return View();
    }
```

Comment: add MedicineTypeId  your Medicine Class and change  "dropdown" to "MedicineTypeId" in your view

Comment: still not saved the FK

Comment: pls can you add httppost controller

Comment: http post controller in my tread/my post

Comment: Viewbag.type is list its not int please can you add ActionResult line for looking binding

Comment: can you give a example ActionResult line for binding?

Comment: After [HttpPost] line for starting function

Comment: oh okay, How i can get the selected list from view?, I edited my Httppost

Comment: Look at my editing

Comment: Oh i see, thanks for your help.